# How can I search a string in some of the tables in a database using JDBC?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jdbc, google-apps-script

Lets say I have table **person** with different columns in a mysql database

the columnns are:

**name, age, description, friends**

I'm trying to find a way to search a certain string in the columns **name, description** and **friends** using jdbc in google app script.

The result should send me back in return an array containing all the lines matching my query

for example here is a database:

```
 ------------------------------------------
| name | age | description      | friends  |
 ------------------------------------------
| John | 20  | "I like Joe"     | Joe Jack |
| Joe  | 32  | "I like me"      | -        |
| Jack | 23  | "I like nothing" | -        |
 ------------------------------------------
```

if my query is `Joe` then **line 1** and **line 2** should be returned as `Joe` appears two times in **line 1** and 1 time in **line 2**.

Here's for the moment what I use to get a line searching by **name**

```
 function getLine(name)
{
  var ret = {};
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM item WHERE name='" + name + "'");
  var numCol = res.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
  var i = 0;
  while (res.next())
  {
    while (i < numCol)
    {
      ret[i]= res.getString(i + 1);
      i++;
    }
  }
  return (ret);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like and OR are the correct keyword for your query.

```
select *
from item
where name = 'Joe'
        or description like concat('%', 'Joe', '%')
        or friends like concat('%', 'Joe', '%');
```